# The solution to the Dyn DNS attack is alternate servers?

Tags: dns

The solution to the Dyn DNS attack is probably having alternate DNS services, right? If our ISP's DNS servers are hit with DDOS, can I just fire up my alternate DNS, which is either hosted by us or another ISP provider, and people will be able to resolve the domain names that I own?

Comment: There is a good question here somewhere.  Consider editing this post to be more inquisitive, don't offer possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The solution to the Dyn DNS attack is probably having alternate DNS
>   services, right?

Having multiple DNS providers serving DNS records for you is a reasonable step to take to avoid being impacted by a DDoS.  The theory is that if multiple providers are serving your DNS records, it's less likely that a DDoS against a single provider will be sufficient to impact your domain.

> If our ISP's DNS servers are hit with DDOS, can I just fire up my
>   alternate DNS, which is either hosted by us or another ISP provider,
>   and everything will be fine?

Well, that's not how it works, exactly.

The Name Servers that people will use to look up names in your domain are listed at the [TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain)'s root servers (if you're "example.com", the "com" root servers have that information).  Those records are updated regularly, but not immediately; it takes [24-48 hours](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/when-will-my-domain-start-working-propagation#propagation) for name server updates to propogate across the roots.

So you can't "fire up alternate DNS" in response to an attack, because of the delay involved.  Your alternate DNS servers need to be up, running, and operational *before* the attack.

Once you've set up multiple providers, if a DDoS hits one of them (like [Dyn](http://dyn.com/)), the chances are another (say [Neustar UltraDNS](https://www.neustar.biz/security/dns-services) or [Akamai Fast DNS](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/solutions/products/cloud-security/fast-dns.jsp)) provider would not be hit at the same time.  So long as some of the servers you've listed as authoritative are responsive, your customers will be able to look up your names and reach your domain.

It will cost more to run a redundant setup like this.  It might cost less than losing several hours of business, depending on your business.

Comment: Of course, if someone has the resources and determination to take DYN down, they might have the resources to take DYN and Akamai down.

Comment: @NPSF3000 Determination doesn't come into it. It's just a bunch of skids with Mirai.

Comment: @NPSF3000 ...or they might have the resources to take the root servers down, in which case everybody is dead in the water.  However, if we're taking defensive measures based on _demonstrated threat patterns_, it's reasonable to assume the provider redundancy (for DNS, for hosting, for almost anything) is a useful defense.

Answer (score 1):

Consider what Akamai did when they observed the deluge of traffic on Brian Krebs' site. They changed the DNS records so the domain resolved to 127.0.0.1 (private IP).

In context of the DynDNS problem, all attacking devices would loop the traffic to their own interfaces. This does suffer from the drawback that the DDoS would continue at least for as long as the DNS record is cached at all attacking endpoints. Assuming most websites have a DNS TTL of 60s nowadays, this does not sound too bad.